# How to get specific value from JSON array

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, ajax

I would like to populate field from an dropdown. For this I used ajax call. I got the below response,

```
[
  {
    "pkApplicationid": 121,
    "success": false,
    "numberOfCustomerUsers": 0,
    "numberofCustomers": 0,
    "dGFFCorpSecInfo": "",
    "dGFFCorpSecDisas": "",
    "securitycompliancecomment": "",
    "dedicatedFTE": 0,
    "noOfCountries": 0,
    "noOfCountriesR": 0,
    "noOfA2AInterfaces": 0,
    "noOfA2AInterfacesR": 0,
    "noOfB2BInterfaces": 0,
    "noOfB2BInterfacesR": 0,
    "totalNoOfUsers": 0,
    "totalNoOfUsersR": 0,
    "noOfStations": 0,
    "productWrite": false,
    "functionalDomainID": 1021,
    "functionalDomainName": "Finance",
    "functionalSubDomainID": 1050,
    "functionalSubDomainName": "Financial Accounting"
  },
  {
    "pkApplicationid": 121,
    "success": false,
    "numberOfCustomerUsers": 0,
    "numberofCustomers": 0,
    "dGFFCorpSecInfo": "",
    "dGFFCorpSecDisas": "",
    "securitycompliancecomment": "",
    "dedicatedFTE": 0,
    "noOfCountries": 0,
    "noOfCountriesR": 0,
    "noOfA2AInterfaces": 0,
    "noOfA2AInterfacesR": 0,
    "noOfB2BInterfaces": 0,
    "noOfB2BInterfacesR": 0,
    "totalNoOfUsers": 0,
    "totalNoOfUsersR": 0,
    "noOfStations": 0,
    "productWrite": false,
    "functionalDomainID": 1023,
    "functionalDomainName": "Customer / Facing",
    "functionalSubDomainID": 1070,
    "functionalSubDomainName": "External World - Customer"
  },
  {
    "pkApplicationid": 121,
    "success": false,
    "numberOfCustomerUsers": 0,
    "numberofCustomers": 0,
    "dGFFCorpSecInfo": "",
    "dGFFCorpSecDisas": "",
    "securitycompliancecomment": "",
    "dedicatedFTE": 0,
    "noOfCountries": 0,
    "noOfCountriesR": 0,
    "noOfA2AInterfaces": 0,
    "noOfA2AInterfacesR": 0,
    "noOfB2BInterfaces": 0,
    "noOfB2BInterfacesR": 0,
    "totalNoOfUsers": 0,
    "totalNoOfUsersR": 0,
    "noOfStations": 0,
    "productWrite": false,
    "functionalDomainID": 1018,
    "functionalDomainName": "Product Operations / Customer Service",
    "functionalSubDomainID": 1390,
    "functionalSubDomainName": "Transactional Handling"
  }
]
```

Ajax call

$.ajax({

```
        url: "servletCall.jsp",
        type: "POST",
        dataType:"html",
        data: {
        appId:appID,    
        functionalID : functionalID,
         async:false,
            cache: false,
        },
        success: function(data){

            console.log(data);
            data = data.replace(/\\n/g, "\\n")  
               .replace(/\\'/g, "\\'")
               .replace(/\\"/g, '\\"')
               .replace(/\\&/g, "\\&")
               .replace(/\\r/g, "\\r")
               .replace(/\\t/g, "\\t")
               .replace(/\\b/g, "\\b")
               .replace(/\\f/g, "\\f");
    data = data.replace(/[\u0000-\u001F]+/g,""); 

var o = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
```

Please help me how to fetch particular value say functionalSubDomainName that I can set in my html table??

Comment: I'm so confused.  `dataType:"html",` <= your response is not html.  It's json.  Why are you not making it dataType json or parsing it yourself?

Comment: did you try `o.functionalSubDomainName` ?

Comment: Thanks for quick reply.Yes I tried. "undefined" is the alert i received. Please help me to resolve this

Comment: It's because it's not one object; it's 3 in an array. You can get it by using `o[2].functionalSubDomainName`. You should probably convert it to one object for easier manipulation.

Comment: if its only one in an array im able to get it with the below function var obj = JSON.parse(data, function (key, value) {
    if (key == "functionalDomainName") {
      return value.toUpperCase();
    } else {
      return value;
    }
  });
 alert(obj.functionalSubDomainName);

Comment: Meant to say o[i].key

Comment: How can i get the same for x in an array.

Comment: You have duplicate values. *which* are you trying to get? Are you just trying to get *all* keys that match that criteria?

Comment: @JoelHager: Yes.I would like to get all values that match the key functionalSubDomainName.

Comment: for (i in myObj.marker) {
  x += "<h2>" + myObj.marker[i].functionalDomainName + "</h2>";
  x +=  myObj.marker[i].functionalSubDomainName ;

} this code works in jquery. But inside AJAX success it returns empty

Comment: Can you show that code?

Comment: @JoelHager: Please find the code that tried in w3schools:)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214046/discussion-between-saranya-and-joel-hager).

Comment: Hi..It worked after adding the below code

Comment: newString = JSON.parse(newString, function(key, value) {
    if (key == 'functionalDomainName') {
    x+="<td>" +value + "</td>";
     return value;
    }